# Deklination von Eigenname von Orten

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

Ich habe gemerkt, dass wenn ein Ortsname als Adjektiv benutzt wird, hat es eine er-Endung unabhängig davon, ob das Nomen männlich, weiblich, sächlich, pluralisch ist.

> Brandenburger Tor
>
> Stuttgarter Nachrichten

Ist das immer der Fall wenn ein Ortsname als Adjektiv benutzt wird?

Comment: Manchmal findet man auch die altdeutsche Formulierung mit -ische am Ende. Bsp: Oldenburger Zeiterung, aber es gibt auch Oldenburgische Landesbank oder Berlinische Galerie. Ansonsten fällt mir aber kein Gegenbeispiel ein. Ob es immer so ist, weiß ich leider nicht.

Comment: Gibt es auf Englisch nicht etwas ähnliches: "New Yorker", "Londoner"?

Comment: @Elena: So ähnlich wie die berühmte "New Yorker Post" oder "Londoner Times" analog zum Beispiel "Stuttgarter Nachrichten"? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich denke, hier handelt es sich nicht um eine Benutzung des Ortsnamens "als Adjektiv", sondern um eine besondere Form des Genitivs.

[Diese Seite](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/attribute/genitiv-namen/) bietet da folgendes schöne Beispiel:

> Berliner Museen (Ortsnamengenitiv mit -er)
>
> Museen Berlins (Genitiv mit -s, auch vorangestellt möglich)
>
> Museen von Berlin (Alternative mit Präposition)

O.g. Seite behauptet, die Formen mit -s „gelten aber als stilistisch weniger schön“, was mir noch nie so aufgefallen ist. Keine Ahnung, wie verlässlich die Seite im Allgemeinen ist. Beim Duden finde ich nur was zur [Zusammen- oder Getrenntschreibung abgeleitetet geografischer Begriffe.](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/ableitungen-geografischer-namen-auf--er-und---i-sch)

Bei mit Vokalen endenden Ortsnamen klingt die -er-Form manchmal vielleicht komisch und es gibt definitiv Ausnahmen. Bei Halle (Salle) kenne ich nur "Hallenser" als -er-Ableitung, in Jena soll es sowohl Jenaer als auch Jenenser geben (mit feinem Bedeutungsunterschied, irgendwas mit eingeboren oder zugezogen), in Rheine z.B. gibt es aber laut wikipedia den Rheiner Anzeiger“ und „Rheiner Report“.

Comment: Ich glaube auch, dass es kein Adjektiv ist. Denn es gibt zum Beispiel das Lübecker Edelmarzipan, aber das Adjektiv für Lübeck ist *lübsch*.